# Create a customer in BigCommerce API v3

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to BigCommerce. I am creating a customer using API v3 in BigCommerce and also able to read it from API as shown below but I am not able to get the customer:

[image]

but if I am creating the customer using API v2 then it is visible in BigCommerce can any body let me what is wrong here.

I have also found that v2 is going to deprecate v2 so, should i use V2.

Comment: Hi @user2550376 
I am unable to get the API response shown in postman. Can you tell me what else settings you did to make this happens ? I am trying with same settings but I am getting 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

The customer resource is only available in V2. There is a newsletter subscriber resource available in V3, but this doesn't support the creation of customer account/entries.

V2 doesn't have a listed deprecation date and is recommended for all resources that don't exist in V3.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am using the V2 to create/update/get customer